# what is the best way to do push notifications using ionic4-5 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, push-notification, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

Just need to know what is the best way to do push notifications using ionic4-5 project (angular4-5, typescript ) for ios and android devices and if there a link that include all the informations i need to complete the scenario, and what the options (i want to take in consideration the number of users , too much like 20 thousand and more)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is the best option. It works well with more number of users. Onesignal is also an option for push notification.

You can check out the difference from below link: 
1) https://mobilejazz.com/blog/push-notifications-firebase-vs-onesignal/
2) https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/onesignal-or-firebase-for-notifications/58803

Answer (score 0):

I my angular project I am working with [google firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) [cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) in my opinion another good platform would be [onesignal](https://onesignal.com/)

Links:

https://firebase.google.com/

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

https://onesignal.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think [one signal](https://onesignal.com/) is the best because ionic also provides plugin for it and I also used it recently.

You can see this for further help:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/

https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-integrate-onesignal-push-notifications-into-an-ionic-3-application-eb2fdc3e6176